# Como saber que tecla fue presionada

Tags: javascript, html, eventos

Necesito que cada vez que se presione una tecla, se ejecute una función, la cual variará en dependencia de la tecla que fue presionada. Por lo que necesito saber que tecla fue presionada.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```js
function onKeyDownHandler() {
     console.log("key pressed ",  String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
}
```

```html
<input onkeydown="onKeyDownHandler();"/>
```

Pero no logro obtener aun el valor de la tecla presionada.

Comment: El código a mi me funciona bien (Chrome para Windows). ¿A qué te refieres con que no logras obtener la letra presionada? ¿Qué sistema operativo y navegador estás usando?

Comment: Recién probé en Firefox para Windows y me devuelve "ReferenceError: event is not defined"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Podrias hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```js
function onKeyDownHandler(event) {

    var codigo = event.which || event.keyCode;

    console.log("Presionada: " + codigo);
     
    if(codigo === 13){
      console.log("Tecla ENTER");
    }

    if(codigo >= 65 && codigo <= 90){
      console.log(String.fromCharCode(codigo));
    }

     
}
```

```html
<input onkeydown="onKeyDownHandler(event);"/>
```

Lo primero que hacemos es incluir la variable `event` en el evento `OnKeyDown`. Esto sirve para que en el momento en que el evento se ejecute, este pueda tener acceso a la informacion respectiva a la tecla.

```
<input onkeydown="onKeyDownHandler(event);"/>
```

Lo segundo es usar esta instruccion:

```
var codigo = event.which || event.keyCode;
```

Esta nos permite obtener el codigo de la tecla presionada. Usamos `which` debido a que el parametro `keyCode` puede no funcionar en todos los navegadores.

Si quieres conocer al respecto de las otras teclas (Escape, Enter, Shift, Etc), puedes mirar [esta pagina](http://keycode.info/), aqui se incluyen ejemplos de los codigos de las teclas.

Acerca del uso de la instruccion `which` y `keyCode` puedes mirar [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471582/javascript-keycode-vs-which), en donde se indica el porque.

Comment: Es `event.keyCode`. A mi tambien me paso

Comment: Para saber otro tipo de caracteres, como `enter`, `backspace`, `ctrl` y `alt`?

Comment: Mira el ejemplo que he agregado

Comment: Usas `wich` y `keyCode`, esto se debe a?

Comment: @Theia Para permitir la portabilidad entre navegadores

Comment: Es culpa del IE

Comment: Si puedes pon de nuevo `String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)`, en caso de alfabeto, para saber que letra fue presionada

Answer (score 3):

## `event.key` es más fácil

```
function onKeyDown(event) {
    const key = event.key; // "A", "1", "Enter", "ArrowRight"...
    console.log("Presionada: " + key);
});
```

[Documentación de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es-MX/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando javascript puro (sin jquery) tienes que hacer algunas validaciones antes.

Tu input tiene que llevar el parámetro **event** ya que en FireFox el **event** no es global y se pasa como parámetro

```
<input onkeydown="onKeyDownHandler(event);"/>
```

En tu función tienes que validar primero de donde viene el **event**, si viene en los parametros (FireFox) o está en el ámbito global (IE). Despues tienes que obtener el valor de la tecla presionada con keyCode (IE y FF) o wich (creo Netscape y Opera).

```
function onKeyDownHandler(evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event;        //Obtenemos el event
    var key = evt.keyCode || evt.which; //Tecla presionada
     console.log("key pressed: " + key);
 }
```

Ten encuenta que el valor de **key** será el código ASCII de la tecla presionada.

Answer (score 1):

## Respuesta corta

1. En lugar de usar la propiead global `event` declárala como argumento de tu función.
2. En lugar de `keyCode` usa `key` para las teclas de caracteres, `shiftKey`, `ctrlKey`, `altKey` y `metaKey`para las teclas mayúsculas, control, alt y Windows / Commmand (Mac) respectivamente.

## Explicación

En Firefox para Windows el código de la pregunta no funciona, devuelve

> "ReferenceError: event is not defined"

Esto ocurre porque en Internet Explorer y Chrome `event` es una propiedad global pero no ocurre así en Firefox.

Por otro lado, de acuerdo a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent tanto `keyCode` como `which` son propiedades obsoletas y en su lugar se recomienda el uso de `key`. Las propiedades `shiftKey`, `ctrlKey`, `altKey` y `metaKey` devolverán `true` si la tecla correspondiente ha sido oprimida.

Aparte de que sean obsoletas no todos los navegadores son compatibles con dichas propiedades.

Una alternativa adicional es el uso de una librería como jQuery la cual pretende hacerse cargo de manejar las variantes de los distintos navegadores.

### Ejemplo usando JavaScript "puro"

En el siguiente ejemplo se agrega el registro de las teclas presionadas al elemento `<input>` y se imprime el resultado a un elemento `<div>`.

```js
var entrada = document.getElementById('entrada');
entrada.addEventListener('keypress',anexar);
var borrar = document.getElementById('borrar');
borrar.addEventListener('click',limpiar);
var salida = document.getElementById('salida');

function anexar(e){
  salida.innerHTML += e.key + '<br />';
}

function limpiar(e){
  entrada.value = '';
  salida.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<input id="entrada"> <input type="button" id="borrar" value="Borrar">
<div id="salida"></div>
```

Lo de poner "puro" es porque el objeto KeyboardEvent no es un objeto de la especificación del lenguaje JavaScript sino que es parte de las Web APIs.

## Ejemplo usando jQuery

Una de las finalidades de jQuery es dar soporte a múltiples navegadores de forma estandarizada. A continuación se muestra un ejemplo en el que se aplican las reomendaciones mencionadas en la sección respuesta corta, la declaración de la variable a la que se asignará el objeto evento y el uso de la propiedad `key`.

```js
$('#entrada').bind('keypress', function(e) {
  $('#salida').append(e.key + '<br />');
});
$('#borrar').bind('click',function(){
  $('#entrada').val('');
  $('#salida').text('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="entrada"> <input type="button" id="borrar" value="Borrar">
<div id="salida"></div>
```